# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException while clicking on a button using expected_conditions presence_of_element_located in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to create an automatic creation for Nike accounts. For that I need to add a phone number. I am coding with Python 3, Selenium and the Chrome Webdriver. This is my current code:

```
    driver.get('https://www.nike.com/de/member/settings')
    element2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/button")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element2)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This codes only works sometimes, I am often getting this error message:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Marten/PycharmProjects/NikeSNKRS/main.py", line 239, in <module>
        element2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/button")))
      File "C:\Users\Marten\PycharmProjects\NikeSNKRS\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
        raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Do you maybe know a way to fix this?
If you want to inspect the page, I created an account for you with which you can go onto the site and inspect the site.
[Click to go to Site](https://www.nike.com/member/settings)

**Account credentials:**

```
Mail: eXrWi9TfA5XSfNcu4uv2q1@peter.de


Password: 5By3oq1Bw
```

I want to click this button:

[image: Button]

Comment: Don't disclose your username & password

Comment: Its just a "fake" account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was quite new to coding, I still am, and I just wanted to create a little script for myself. Also I was quite unexperienced with XPaths. I recommend everybody who stumbles upon this issue, to read through [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

I used this XPath, instead:
`//div[@class="mex-mobile-input"]/div/div/div[2]/button`

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could tell you that this works 100% of the time (it doesn't) but perhaps it will get you a bit closer. I think one of the problems is that when you login the settings for **Account** are not open and visible (at least that is always the case for me) and you have to first click on the **Account** selection at the left to reveal the Mobil settings. Unfortunately, even that does not work 100% of the time, at least not with the following code (I am using basic element click calls). But I offer this up for what it's worth:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) # wait up to 10 seconds before calls to find elements time out
    driver.get('https://www.nike.com/member/settings')
    input('pausing for login ...') # to allow manual login
    driver.get('https://www.nike.com/member/settings')
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div') # Account settings
    elem.click()
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/button')
    elem.click()
finally:
    input('pausing for inspection') # to allow inspection
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try it! :) Ill give you a response on Thursday.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Hinzufügen** instead of `presence_of_element_located()` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Mobilnummer hinzufügen']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *aria-label* attribute:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Mobilnummer hinzufügen']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *innerText* attribute:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'Hinzufügen')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but i am using proxys from different countries. And I think your solution would only work with german proxys, or when the language is set to german.

Comment: @MatrixSpielt I didn't consider the case of language locale. But the text you were speaking about i.e. **Hinzufügen** should be located by the locator strategies without any failure.

Comment: Okay, ive tried your method, but I constantly get this error code now: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marten/PycharmProjects/NikeSNKRS/testdelete.py", line 221, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Mobilnummer hinzufügen']"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\Marten\PycharmProjects\NikeSNKRS\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: