# XPATH is changing

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using Python 3 and Selenium(Chromedriver). I want to check for a element with this command.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/button"))).click()
```

The problem is that the XPATH is constantly changing between two paths:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/button
/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/button
```

I want to tell Python, that if the element is not found, it should search for the other XPATH.

If you know a method to find the element without the XPATH, i would also be happy with the solution.
It does not work if you search for the elemnt by its containing text, because the language from the sites changes if use a proxy.
This is the "Inspect Element" code of the button:

```
<button aria-label="Mobilnummer hinzufügen" class="bg-white css-1eajgu7 ex41m6f0 btn-secondary-dark " type="button">Hinzufügen</button>
```

Comment: Try `(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-secondary-dark")`

Comment: No, does not work. Your code selects the first button which is found. Still if there was only one button, it would be a good solution. Thanks!

Comment: add some more HTML so we can include ancestors in selector

Comment: Hey, you can access the site with a username and password which I have provided at the end of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63784036/selenium-common-exceptions-timeoutexception-while-clicking-on-a-button-using-exp The button "Add Phone number" is the button I mean.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Hinzufügen** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.bg-white.btn-secondary-dark[aria-label='Mobilnummer hinzufügen']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Mobilnummer hinzufügen' and text()='Hinzufügen']").click()
  ```

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.bg-white.btn-secondary-dark[aria-label='Mobilnummer hinzufügen']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Mobilnummer hinzufügen' and text()='Hinzufügen']))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but that wont work because you used the language-keywords. :) Still thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this XPath:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'mex-mobile-phone')]//button[contains(@class, 'btn-secondary-dark')]
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marten/PycharmProjects/NikeSNKRS/testdelete.py", line 228, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'mex-mobile-phone')]//button[contains(@class, 'btn-secondary-dark')]"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\Marten\PycharmProjects\NikeSNKRS\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @MatrixSpielt Hmm... Works fine for me. Do you mean this page https://www.nike.com/de/member/settings, right?

Comment: I have completely rewritten my code. The problem was that the IDs were constantly changing.